# Allow clicks and click-through's

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have a `Grid` over a `Button` (They are both directly on another Grid, but the `Grid` is "above"). I need to subscribe to certain events in the `Grid`, but still be able to click on the `Button`. I set the `Background` of the `Grid` to `Transparent`, to get it to raise events, but then the `Button` isn't clickable. Is there any way to leave `IsHitTestVisible = true` but let the click go to the next element as well?

Answer (score 2):

I'd first look at whether you can put the button above the grid.  You can just move it in the XAML - the further down an element declaration is in the XAML, the higher the z-order.

If you definitely cannot do this, you could override the UI element MouseUp or MouseDown methods and control the setting of the handled property to allow the subsequent elements in the tree to take the clicks.

If you only wanted to restrict this to a specific control, you could inspect the "OriginalSource" property (since all these event args inherit from RoutedEventArgs) to see what the source of the click was and act accordingly:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = e.OriginalSource as Grid;
    if (grid != null && grid.Tag = "yourgridname") e.Handled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately what I need is exactly what I described, in order to make a workaround work for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303617/prevent-a-scrollviewers-scrolling-conditionally . I'm trying to detect the ScrollViewer's scrolling with a Grid above it, before it gets to the ScrollViewer. (And this question is only a simplification with the pertinent parts for the workaround.)

Comment: What I've given you (setting e.Handled) will allow the click to go to the next element under it ...

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but perhaps did somethhing wrong. I need to try it again.