# Prevent a ScrollViewer's scrolling conditionally

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

Is there any way to not only be *notified* of a `ScrollViewer`'s scroll, but to be able to *prevent* it. Something like a `ScrollChanging` event so I can set `e.Cancel` to `true`?

(I don't want to disable scrolling, nor do I want to implement it myself because it seems impossible to get the `ScrollBar`'s events to detect a user dragging them. At least in **UWP**.)

**The problem is** that `ScrollViewer_PointerWheelChanged` isn't raised when it scrolls. Only when it doesn't have any need to scroll does it fire.

Comment: Rather than relying on being notified, wouldn't it be better to disable scrolling preemptively? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollmode.aspx

Comment: @KooKiz Thanks, But that's not a (good) option. (That's why I wrote the second paragraph in my question. The one in parentheses.)

Comment: Could always watch the [VerticalOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset) / HorizontalOffset for property change and then disable scrolling a few different ways.